# Is console.log asynchronous?

Tags: console

I had an incident in my Angular 6 application the other day involving some code that looked like this:

```
console.log('before:', value);
this.changeValue(value);
console.log('after:', value);
```

changeValue() modifies value in some way. I expected to see the unmodified value in the console before the call to changeValue() then the modified value after. Instead I saw the modified value before and after.

I guess it proved that my changeValue() function worked, but it also indicated to me that console.log() is asynchronous--that is, it doesn't print out the value to the console right away; it waits for a bit... and when it finally does print the value, it's the value as it is at that moment. In other words, the first call to console.log() above waited until after the call to changeValue() before printing, and when it did, the value had already changed.

So am I correct in inferring that console.log() is asynchronous. If so, why is that? It causes a lot of confusion when debugging.

Comment: In what way is the value modified? Is it an object/dict or an array? Does the changeValue() function assign a whole new object to the variable or does it mutate the passed-in object?

Comment: ChangeValue(value) is like this: changeValue(value: string) { value += ' xxx'; }

Answer (score 1):

No, console.log() is synchronous. It's actually your changeValue() function that doesn't work the way you think.

First, JavaScript doesn't pass variables by reference, but by [pointer to object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing) (as do many other languages). So although the variable `value` inside your function and the variable `value` in the outer scope both hold the same object, they are still separate variables. Mutatin the object affects both variables, but direct assignments to one variable **do not** affect the other. For example, this obviously **wouldn't** work:

```
function changeValue(x) { x = 123; }
```

Second, in JavaScript the shorthand assignment `a += b` does not mutate the existing object stored in `a`. Instead it works exactly like `a = a + b` and assigns a *new* object to the variable. As mentioned above, this only affects the variable *inside* the function, but doesn't affect the one outside, so your changes are lost after the function returns.

More examples:

```
function willwork(obj) { obj.foo = "bar"; }
function willwork(obj) { obj["foo"] = 1234; }
function willwork(obj) { obj.push("foo"); }

function wontwork(obj) { obj = "foo"; }
function wontwork(obj) { obj += 123; }
function wontwork(obj) { obj = obj + 123; }
```